# How to cron a bash script which requires root user access to run

Tags: linux, bash, shell, csh

I have a bash script that has a function written in Perl script called in the bash script. But when I try to run the script in cron the cron is not able to fetch the script as it says it requires root user access. When I execute the script I switch to the data manager role to execute. What can I do so that cron can also execute the script?

Few suggested converting the bash script into csh script also for reference asked me to add

```
source /central/confg/global.cshrc
```

this is in the script but I am not good at shell scripting so I am having trouble converting bash script into csh script.
If anyone has any ideas what can be done here please share.

Comment: It's hard to tell from the info you've given what's going on. Do you know specifically why it says it requires root access? Does running the script normally (i.e. not with cron) work, or does that also say it requires root? And it doesn't make sense that using csh would have anything to do with this; who suggested converting it to csh, and do you have any idea why they thought that'd help?

Answer (score 0):

add the below line into file: `/etc/sudoers`

`$(USERNAME) ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: $(PATH TO SCRIPT)`

Answer (score 0):

The default user is root if no user is specified as a parameter when creating a cronjob. Give the script the executable permissions to run successfully and to set any environment variables the root user needs to run the script.

Note: The root user should not be used for security reasons unless necessary.

Comment: This is not correct; there is no default user for cron jobs. In the system-wide crontab files (usually /etc/crontab and files in /etc/cron.d/), there's an explicit username-to-run-as field after the time & date fields, and before the command. In per-user crontab files (usually in /var/spool/cron/crontabs/), the username is controlled by the filename (e.g. entries in /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root run as root, entries in /var/spool/cron/crontabs/fred run as fred, etc).